# Is using pub serve as a production webserver correct?

Tags: dart, webserver, dart-pub

In the docs of `pub serve` it's written

> This command starts up a development server, or dev server, for your Dart web app. The dev server is an HTTP server on localhost that serves up your web app’s assets.

As it states it's a "dev server", does it mean I should not use `pub serve` as a production web server? What are the alternatives?

Also as of right now when I use `pub serve` it also serves my tests on another port (I don't think this is desirable for production, hence this question). Is there an option in pub to prevent it from serving my tests and use `pub serve --mode=release`? (if that's appropriate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pub serve` is definitely **not** for production. For production generate JavaScript output using `pub build` and serve the result (from `build/web`) with any production web server of your choice (like Apache, Nginx, ...)